# Powershell Store column values into string

Tags: powershell, split, exchange-server

I would like to get the column values into array. Currently it is not possible because of 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData' due to format-table pipeline.

```
$mailboxnames = get-mailboxdatabase | ft Name

$splits=@()
foreach($names in $mailboxnames){
  $splits += $names.split('-')
}
$splits
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just not have to use format table.

```
$mailboxDBs = get-mailboxdatabase
foreach ($mailboxDB in $mailboxDBs)
{
 $mailboxDB.name
}

Mailbox Database 1558034411
archiveMail
```

**Don't forget everything is OBJECT in Powershell you are playing on the top of .NET**

So you've got two freinds :
 1.The gettype() method which gives you the type of an object
 2.The Get-Member CmdLet which help you on properties, and methods of an object

Get-member have many parameters that can help but try :

```
$mailboxDBs | Get-Member
```

Comment: I always thought it is like any other languages by just getting the list and putting into array. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Or use the pipeline:

```
$db = Get-MailboxDatabase | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
```